# Visibility of Swift public names in binary code

Tags: swift, visibility

The difference between Swift's  `public` and `internal` is clear for a library project: the `public` names are visible in the binary code,  while `internal` names are hidden.

What if I use `public` names in a main (non-library) project. Will these names still appear in the binary code?

Comment: Why do you believe `internal` names are hidden in the binary? (They're not. In some cases they may be optimized out, but they're not hidden.)

Comment: Rob Napier. That's sad. Given that Swift is a compiler I assume all non-external names to be replaced by internal references. Maybe  keeping names is somehow related to bitcode, and if bitcode is disabled they will not appear.

Comment: It's not related to bitcode. How would code like `print(type(of: object))`work if the names of the types weren't somewhere in the binary? This isn't an accident.